# set the value of variable from combined values of rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

So i have the following table, @tmpRespTBL

[image]

Somewhere in my proc, i have the variable @xmlString. I want the value of my @xmlString to be the combined values of all the rows on the @tmpRespTBL table Responses column.

My output should be:

```
@xmlString = '<x id="3" name="Good" val="0" seq="0" createsr="0" /><x id="4" name="Fair" val="0" seq="0" createsr="0" /><x id="5" name="Needs Repair" val="1" seq="0" createsr="0" /><x id="6" name="Not Inspected" val="1" seq="0" createsr="0" /><x id="7" name="N/A" val="1" seq="0" createsr="1" />'
```

How do i do that in sql?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT @xmlString = COALESCE(@xmlString+',' , '') + CAST( Responses AS Varchar(max))
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Have you tried this where the column in the table is the data type  XML?

Comment: Try it and tell me. However I think OP wants the result to be XML, not text. You are adding a comma between the XML parts and that is not there in the expected output in the Q. And if you cast to something it should probably be nvarchar since XML in SQL server is Unicode. A cast will also not do what you want with entities in the XML like `&amp;` and `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT t.Responses  as '*'
FROM @tmpRespTBL AS t   
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: I think it will return in XML format but he already having xml format